# Visual Studio Code Update IP’s

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio Code installed on a PC within my company's network. I'm testing the update feature, so I have version 0.10.6 installed. When I check for updates I receive a message that no updates are available. I been working with my company's network team to configure our proxy server to allow VS Code to update when needed. Using Wire Shark we've identified the two IP addresses below that VS Code contacts to check for updates. Are there are any additional IP addresses that are used by VS Code for updates?

- 104.40.183.236
- 72.21.81.200

Answer (score 0):

These are the URLs that VS Code pings during update:

> https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net
>
> https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net